# Retrieve user profile in Cognito Federated Identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, user-profile, federated-identity, amazon-cognito

I'm currently exploring the AWS stack and am therefore building a simple web app. I plan on using:

- S3 to host the static contents
- DynamoDB to store user data
- Lambda + API Gateway for backend logic
- Cognito Federated Identities to authenticate users

I currently have a small tracer bullet application working that allows the user to authenticate with Google (through Cognito) and retrieve some data through a Lambda from DynamoDB. Now I want to extend it.

The next thing I want to do (and am failing to achieve) is to actually store the user name and e-mail of the authenticated user. Storing it shouldn't be a big problem, but retrieving it is. I know I initially got the data from Google because when I inspect the ID token (on JWT.io) I got from Google, I can clearly see my e-mail and name. This is the token I sent to AWS Cognito in exchange for a Cognito token.

I was expecting to be able to access this data again in my Lambda function, but I fail to figure out how actually. I understand Cognito performs a one way hash on the retrieved ID token, but I would expect some options to actually retrieve relevant user data from the token. After all, by authentication through Google (or any other IdP) a user already consented to sharing some personal data.

I feel I fail to see something obvious. Is there any feature in AWS that solves this? Is there a moment (not on the client side) where I can inspect the ID token and do some magic with it? Or should I solve this in some different way?

If the latter is the case: what would be the preferred way? I don't want users to tell me their personal data, because then I would also need some way to validate it.